# how to incorporate dojo confirm dialog into xslt transformation?

Tags: xslt, dialog, dojo, confirm

The bottom line is that I need a (dojo) confirm yes-no dialog, and I need to use it inside xsl code.

The idea is that I generate two buttons using xslt transformation, the first one is edit and the second one is delete. The latter should open up the confirm dialog.
Here is the xsl code I use to create those buttons.

```
 <xsl:template match="report:submit-button">
        <script type="text/javascript">require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button"]);</script>

        <button type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
            <xsl:if test="@name">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="@value">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>

        </button>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am really new to dojo but I found some tutorials so I have the code below.

```
<div>
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        Please confirm if you would like to delete the selected ${message}. <p/>
        This operation cannot be undone.
    </div>

    <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" >OK</button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" >Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>

var myWidget = new MyWidget({
  message: "Member"
});

var myDialog4 = new Dialog({
  title: "My Dialog 4",
  content: myWidget
});

myDialog4.show();
```

My question is how to incorporate dojo into the xsl code? If it were a simple and short javascipt function, something like alert() or confirm, then I would add another attribute with the value of "onclick", like this:

```
<xsl:if test="@verifyPopUp">
     <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
         var c = confirm("Please confirm deleting this item");                 
      </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

but this long and somehow cumbersome dojo-code above does not seem to be a perfect fit for that. Any advice is appricated.

Comment: Not sure i understand, in your above example you have two buttons, but then in the dojo example you are showing a dojo dialog.  are you trying to get 2 buttons and have then execute an action onclick? or do you want a dojo dialog

Comment: I have 2 ordinary buttons. One of them is "delete". The other one is irrelevant. If somebody clicks on "delete", a dojo confirm dialog should appear with two brand new buttons; "yes, I want to delete it" and "no, don't delete it"